# Building relation in Django rest_framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, relationship

```
class Company(Timestampable, SoftDeletes):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, editable=False, default = uuid.uuid4)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length=1, max_length=255, field_name = 'name')])
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length=1, max_length=255, field_name = 'industry')])
    scale = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices = SCALE_OF_COMPANY, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length=1, max_length=255, field_name = 'scale')]) 
    total_employees = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length = 1, max_length = 500, field_name = 'total_employees')])
    headquarter = models.CharField(max_length = 256, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length=1, max_length=256, field_name = 'headquarter')])
    has_branches = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    about_company = models.TextField(null=True, max_length =500, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length=1, max_length=256, field_name = 'about_company')])
    status = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=256, choices= COMPANY_STATUSES, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length=1, max_length=255, field_name = 'company_status')], default = 'active' )
    vision = models.TextField(null=True,max_length=500, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length = 1, max_length =255, field_name ='vision')])
    values = models.TextField(null=True,max_length=500, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length = 1, max_length =255, field_name ='values')])
    mission = models.TextField(null=True,max_length=500, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length = 1, max_length =255, field_name ='mission')])
    
    culture = models.TextField(null=True,max_length=500, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length = 1, max_length =255, field_name ='culture')])
    linkedin_url = models.URLField(max_length = 128, unique=True, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length = 1, max_length= 128, field_name = 'linkedin')])
    website_url = models.URLField(max_length = 128, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length=1, max_length = 128, field_name = 'website')])
    
    pan = models.CharField(max_length = 256, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length = 1, max_length = 256, field_name = 'pan')])
    gst = models.CharField(max_length = 256, validators=[CustomLengthValidator(min_length = 1, max_length = 256, field_name = 'gst')])
```

This is the company model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser, Timestampable, SoftDeletes):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    country_code_key = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    contact_verified_status = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    contact_verified_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    email_verified_status = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    email_verified_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"
        unique_together = [["country_code", "contact"]]
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['contact_verified_status']),
            models.Index(fields=['email_verified_status']),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

this is the user model,
When the user logins, i should get the details of user with the company 'id' or 'name'

I tried making companies as a ForignKey field but it didnt work